# Optimize code to avoid Total Request Limit Exceeded

Tags: callout

I have a callout that is getting a zip file containing a csv from an endpoint. It seems my code making too many API requests since I am getting 'Total Request Limit Exceeded' error.

At the moment I am just counting how many lines are being read before I can do further processing of the data received. My intention is to be able to process up to 10000 records. I ran a query right before the error and the JobItemsProcessed, was showing almost 7000.

I thought the callout is made only once. Could someone please help me optimize it to avoid the hitting the api limit? Thanks!

The CSViterator is based on [this](https://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/) example

```
global with sharing class ReadAndPopulateBatch implements Database.batchable<String>, Database.AllowsCallouts
{
   private String m_csvFile;
   private Integer m_startRow;
   private Parser m_parser;
   private static final Integer SCOPE_SIZE = 100;
   public static final String CR = '\r';
   public static final String LF = '\n';
   public String crlf = CR + LF;
   Blob csvBlob;
   public Integer count = 0;


   global Iterable<String> start(Database.batchableContext batchableContext)
   {
       
       Blob csvfile = Callout.makeCallout();
       String m_csvFile = csvfile.toString();       
       return new CSVIterator(m_csvFile, crlf);
   }
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<String> scope)  
   {
       
       String csvFile = '';
       for(String row : scope)
       {
          csvFile += row + crlf;
          csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(csvFile);

       }
       List<List<String>> csvLines = CsvReader.readIETFRFC4180CSVFile(csvBlob);
       count++;

   }
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext){
    System.debug(' Records processed. Shazam!' + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: the limit is an org daily limit; perhaps other applications have maxed the limit. Check `Setup | Company Information` to see your current limit and amount used. As coded above, the callout is made once per batchable start.

Comment: I checked the system overview and it shows 15128 api requests. Its my dev org and there is no other app running. I ran the same code in another dev org and got the same total request limit.

Comment: Dev Edition is only allowed 15000 API calls per day so either you are running this batch job every few seconds or makeCallout is making multiple callouts or you have something else going on in your dev org (including packages) that is sucking up your api limits

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand. What I thought is that the way I wrote that code above, it should only make one callout. Any suggestions on how to improve it? I don't understand why it is doing it more than once.

Comment: Your code is fine; the problem lies elsewhere - something else in your org is making API calls - check for Scheduled jobs, Apex jobs in setup

Comment: Thanks @cropredy I made changes to the quantity passed to the batch scheduler from 1 to 20 and it worked.

Comment: wait, what? you had a scheduler that called the batchable multiple times?

Comment: No. I had set the scheduler with a value of 1 to be able to process the csv row by row. After changing to 20 lines per batch, the error was gone. Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject,20);

Comment: i'm still puzzled, the batchable `start()` is called once per `Database.executeBatch` and this (per your code) does the callout. The scope parameter `(1, 20, 200)` decides how many of the iterated records are passed to each `execute()` transaction. Did you mask out in OP the work done by `execute()` - which might have done more callouts?